# Валидация формы PHP

Tags: php, валидация

Помогите пожалуйста дописать код. Мне нужно к этому коду дописать проверку формы на обязательное заполнение атрибутов input (name, phone).

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
    if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {$comment = $_POST['comment'];}
    if (isset($_POST['formData'])) {$formData = $_POST['formData'];}

    $to = "sevenpav@gmail.com"; 
    $sendfrom   = "hello@zelsmoke.ru"; 
    $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $subject = "$formData";
    $message = "$formData
 <b>Имя пославшего:</b> $name
<b>Телефон:</b> $phone
 <b>Почта:</b> $email
<b>Комментарий:</b> $comment";
    $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($send == 'true')
    {
    echo '<center>

Спасибо за заказ! В течение 10 минут с Вами свяжется менеджер.

</center>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<center>

<b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!</b>

</center>';
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "Попробуйте еще раз";
}?>
```

Comment: Конкретно в чем вопрос? В чем помочь то? И форматируйте код!

Answer (score 2):

валидация происходит добавление проверочных условий. 
для php > 5.2 вот это:

```
filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Обычно используют регулярные выражения.

```
if(preg_match("/[0-9a-z_\.\-]+@[0-9a-z_\.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/i", $email))

{
// проверка успешно пройдена

}
```

Для e-mail  иногда проверяют доступность получения писем на указанный домен ( проверка МХ записей). Кроме того, при указании

```
<input type="email" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}">
```

и

```
<input type="tel" pattern="(\+?\d[- .]*){7,13}" >
```

первично проверка будет происходить на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 0):

Для полей, которые надо обязательно заполнить, в html к ним добавьте атрибут required.

Можно сделать при помощи php, но это если Вы используете технологию ajax, тогда выводить через php скрипт, а через скрипт уже уведомлять человека, что надо заполнить поле.